CORS blocking requests from imported PHP scripts
I'm having trouble getting CORS to accept cross-origin requests from imported PHP scripts.  I have two subdomains for my website: 'php.<my wesbite>.com', which is where I host my PHP scripts, and 'admin.<my website>.com', which is where I host my Vue.js admin control panel.
I have a file called 'common_headers.php' for setting the CORS headers, which I import via 'require' in my other PHP scripts.  In 'get_flagges_policies.php' and 'validate_session_token.php', I do this at the very top of the files.  However, CORS only accepts 'get_flagged_policies' if I don't import 'validate_session_token'.
I have tried manually adding the headers to 'validate_session_token', but this does not resolve the issue.  My only solution at this time is to paste the code for validating session tokens into my flagged policies script, but then I would have to do the same for all of my PHP scripts which require validation.

php.<my website>.com/miscellaneous/common_headers.php:
<?php
function setCommonHeaders() {
    $allowedOrigins = [
        'https://php.<my website>.com',
        'https://admin.<my website>.com',
        'https://www.<my website>.com',
    ];

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
        $parsedUrl = parse_url($origin);
        $host = $parsedUrl['host'] ?? '';

        if (in_array($origin, $allowedOrigins) || preg_match('/(^|\.)<my website>\.com$/', $host)) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $origin);
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET");
            header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");

            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
                header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    }
}
?>

php.<my website>.com/insurance/get_flagged_policies.php:
<?php
require '../miscellaneous/common_headers.php';
setCommonHeaders();

include '../../connect.php';

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$limit = isset($input['limit']) ? (int) $input['limit'] : 20;
$offset = isset($input['offset']) ? (int) $input['offset'] : 0;

$session_token = $input['session_token'];
require '../session/validate_session_token.php';    //  This line is causing the CORS error 
validateSessionToken($conn, $session_token, true);

// ... rest of script

php.<my website>.com/session/validate_session_token.php:
<?php
require '../miscellaneous/common_headers.php';
setCommonHeaders();

function validateSessionToken($conn, $session_token, $adminRequired) {

    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        exit('user_not_logged_in');
    }

    // ... rest of script


If you do var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']); what does it show?

Could this be a simple issue of defining the setCommonHeaders() function twice because you require '../miscellaneous/common_headers.php'; twice? The description of the problem you're having isn't very clear.

Use require_once rather than require to prevent duplication.

@Barmar, oddly, echoing var_dump at the end of the setCommonHeaders() function returns NULL; same if I add it in get_flagged_policies.  Also, replacing require with require_once doesn't resolve the issue.

For some reason your browser isn't sending the Origin: header. I'm not sure why, since any browsers that implement CORS should send this.

Could it also possibly be related to the fact that I'm using a different subdomain for the admin control panel?  The Vue.js project is hosted at admin..com whereas the scripts are hosted at php..com.

Note that switching on error reporting in PHP could have told you what the problem is.

Regardless of your issue, you never need to list Access-Control-Allow-Headers in the value of the header of the same name.

Adding __DIR__ to the directory in get_flagged_policies.php resolved the issue.  I also changed require to require_once.
require_once __DIR__ . '/../session/validate_session_token.php';


Using relative paths for includes is often problematic, and should probably be avoided. Your solution still isn't ideal, given the /../ in the path. See this old comment by Rick Garcia. Do you know why your solution works?
